# integral over unit ball?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Let's consider the collection of $C^1$ functions, where $k=1,2,\ldots,(n-1)$: 
$$g_k:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$ where: $$
g_k=g_k(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$$

Then a new map $f$ is defined as follows: $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that: $$f(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_n)=(x_1, g_1(x_1)+2x_2, g_2(x_1,x_2) + 3x_3, \ldots, g_{n-1}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})+nx_n)$$

How can find the volume of $f((0,1)^n)$ where $(0,1)^n$ is an open unit cube $(0,1)^n$?

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: @draks: I am solving this problems for practice

Comment: Can you use the change of variables formula? The derivative of $f$ is triangular, so the Jacobian might be easy to compute. In fact, the Jacobian seems to be $n!$ (do you have a typo. in your expression for $f$, if not, I'm not sure what the general term is?).

Comment: The change of variables formula gives $\int_{\phi(U)} g(y) dy = \int_U g(\phi(x)) J_{\phi} (x) dx$. Use $\phi = f$, $g = 1$.

Comment: Looks good to me. But you should check to make sure you are comfortable with the application.

Comment: @draks: These problems are for an exam...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By change of variables formula, if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ is open     and $G: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R^{n}}$ is a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{G(\Omega)} f(x) dx = \int_{\Omega)}f \circ G(x)| det D_xG| dx
\end{equation}
Then
$$
L^{n}(f((0,1)^{n})) =  \int_{f((0,1)^{n})} 1 dx =  \int_{(0,1)^{n}} |det D_x f| dx
$$

But,
$$ D_xf = \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
D_1 g_1(x_1) & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
D_1 g_2(x_1,x_2) & D_2 g_2(x_1,x_2)& 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & 0 & 0\\
D_1 g_{n-1}(x*) & D_2 g_{n-1}(x*) &  D_3 g_{n-1}(x*)& \cdots & D_{n-1}g_{n-1}(x*)& n \\
\end{array}
\right] $$
Where $x* = (x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_{n-1})$

Hence
$$ L^{n}(f((0,1)^{n}))= n!L^{n}(0,1)^{n}.$$